# How to start working in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have installed the NetBeans IDE. Now I want to start to do something. But I do not understand the idea of the "project". I know that I can have source files, then I can compile them and execute. But what does the project mean?

OK. I wanted to figure out that by opening a "New Project". But when I start it I need to select between the "Java Application", "Java Desktop Application", "Java Class Library" and so on. I have no idea what it means.

I just want to write a program which does certain things (track keyboard activity). How should I classify it? Java Application? Java Desktop Application? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go straight to Java Application. Java Desktop Application will make you learn a framework which is unnecesary at this point of your learning curve.

If you want to do a simple example, take a look here: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-intro.html or the more general http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-se.html

Keep on working it, man.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Application. You'll learn the rest later.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a Java Application project. That's OK for an application you would start with the usual `java` command from the console.

Answer (score 0):

Java application is a command prompt application. Java Desktop Application is an application with a User Interface. You will be able to create the User Interface with a form designer, if you choose this.

Also note that Java isn't a suitable language for tracking keyboard activity. This will be platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has a very great [documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/index.html) section, Start from there. Documentation is the great place to start learning a new tool and they have excellent screen casts too.I would recommend you choose a learning trail and follow it.